# Why adiabatic and reversible process is needed to write $\delta p = \frac{d p}{d\rho} \, \delta\rho$?

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, pressure, acoustics

Consider a fluid in thermodynamic equilibrium, with pressure $p_0$ and energy density $\rho_0$.  You then create a small local perturbation to produce a sound wave:
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\rho &= \rho_0 + \delta\rho,
&p &= p_0 + \delta p,
\end{align}
where $\delta \rho \ll \rho_0$.  The fluid's state equation is defined by a relation like $p(\rho)$.  Is it necessary to state that the sound wave generation is *adiabatic* and *reversible* to write the following?
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\delta p = \frac{d p}{d\rho} \, \delta\rho.
\end{equation}
Is it true that if the process isn't adiabatic or reversible, then the pressure differential should include more terms like the following?
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\delta p = \frac{\partial p}{\partial\rho} \, \delta\rho + \frac{\partial p}{\partial S} \, \delta S + \dots,
\end{equation}
so actually pressure $p$ isn't a function of energy density alone?  If so, what are the independant variables that $p$ should depends on?

Comment: Without any further discussion of what this notation means, it's really impossible to say...

Comment: @knzhou, what notation?  I defined the energy density and pressure of the fluid.

Comment: For example, "the fluid's state equation is defined by a relation like $p(\rho)$". That certainly doesn't make sense for most fluids I know of, such as an ideal gas. If you mean that you have a system where $p$ only depends on $\rho$, then of course your (2) is trivially true.

Comment: @knzhou, this is what I want to clear up.  $p(\rho)$ is a generic function of energy density (for a general fluid).  AFAIK, it makes sense.  For example:  an ultra-relativistic fluid has $p = \frac{1}{3} \, \rho$.  For a polytrope (i.e. perfect gas), we have $p = \kappa \, \rho_{\text{mass}}^{\gamma}$.  If $p$ depends only on $\rho$, then of course (2) is trivial.  But then why do we have to say that the wave generation is *adiabatic* and *reversible*?

Comment: An equation of state in the standard sense is a relationship between $p$, $\rho$, and $T$. You can only ignore $T$ if you have some additional information.

Comment: One possible additional piece of information is if you know $S$ (which stays the same if the process is adiabatic and reversible).

Comment: @knzhou, so you say that $p = \mathcal{P}(\rho, S)$ (or $p = \mathcal{Q}(\rho, T)$), so we generally have the differential (3) in a non-adiabatic process?

Comment: I believe that things are clear now.  The physics is almost obvious, actually.  Aaah, thermodynamics!